# TypeScript refactoring. Update Collection

Tags: refactoring, typescript

I have a lot of foreach in TypeScript, some of them:

```
 $.each(obj.triggers, function (index, value) {
                (<any>sc.triggers).push(Trigger.objectToTrigger(value));
            });    
$.each(obj.notStartTriggers, function (index, value) {
                (<any>sc.notStartTriggers).push(Trigger.objectToTrigger(value));
            });
```

How I can refactor this foreach's? I need one method for this foreach.

Thanks to all. I need update sc.notStartTriggers collection, not add(push)?

Comment: I don't think this question is clear enough to get (m)any answers. What exactly are you trying to do, what have you tried, and what is or isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a property on `obj` and the same property on `sc` that you want to loop on using Trigger. So here is a function to take these as parameters:

```
function process(obj,sc,property:string,Trigger){
    $.each(obj[property], function (index, value) {
                (sc[property]).push(Trigger.objectToTrigger(value));
            });     
}

process(obj,sc,"triggers",Trigger);
process(obj,sc,"notStartTriggers",Trigger);
```

Note that the following are equivalent in javascript / typescript:

```
x.asdf
x["asdf"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of a refactor on your code would probably be to remove the casting, rather than to remove the slight duplication.

Also, you don't need to go as far as `any`, as the operations you are looking for are from an array, so you could use `any[]` which makes at least that much known.

I have stretched Robert C Martin's rule on the number of parameters by allowing two arguments to be passed to my method :) - the arguments are in the order implied by the method name, add *trigger* to *array*.

```
function addTriggerToArray(trigger: any, triggerArray: any[]) {
    triggerArray.push(trigger);
}

$.each(obj.triggers, function (index, value) {
    addTriggerToArray(Trigger.objectToTrigger(value), sc.triggers);
});    
$.each(obj.notStartTriggers, function (index, value) {
    addTriggerToArray(Trigger.objectToTrigger(value), sc.notStartTriggers);
});
```

To update existing items you would use...

```
function updateTrigger(trigger: any, index: number, triggerArray: any[]) {
    triggerArray[index] = trigger;
}

$.each(obj.triggers, function (index, value) {
    updateTrigger(Trigger.objectToTrigger(value), index, sc.triggers);
});    
$.each(obj.notStartTriggers, function (index, value) {
    updateTrigger(Trigger.objectToTrigger(value), index, sc.notStartTriggers);
});
```

Comment: Thanks to all. I need update sc.notStartTriggers collection, not add(push)?

Comment: To update an item in the collection, you would need to know the index, so you would have to pass that too: `triggerArray[index] = trigger;`.

Comment: In this function addTriggerToArray(trigger: any, triggerArray: any[]) {
    triggerArray.push(trigger);
} I can't use index

Comment: You would have to add the parameter and pass the argument... I'll add an example.